# Cracked my ipad 3 a little. What should I do?

Tags: ipad, screen, damage

I have cracked the screen of iPad only down the middle and a little on the side.

I have only had for about 6 months what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you purchased the AppleCare extended warranty for your iPad before you broke it, you can get your iPad replaced for a fee of, I believe, US$60 from the Apple Store or an authorized Apple dealer. If you did not purchase the AppleCare extended warranty before you damaged your iPad, there is nothing you can do other than pay the full price plus labor for a replacement screen.

If you do get it repaired, or purchase a replacement, by all means buy a good case for your iPad to protect it from further damage.

Comment: Have not got apple care